# (Android Studio) E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xae6b28f0

Tags: java, android, screen, splash-screen

Hello i got this message when try to simulate my apps in emulator (Nexus 5 API 23) using android studio.

Here is my code of

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.shalahuddinn.menurestoran">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".splashscreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

splashscreen.java

```
package com.example.shalahuddinn.menurestoran;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class splashscreen extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splashscreen);
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                startActivity(new Intent(splashscreen.this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();
}
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.shalahuddinn.menurestoran;

import android.icu.text.NumberFormat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Integer qB2 = 0;
Integer pB2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
public void decrementB2 (View view) {
    if (qB2>0) {
        qB2 = (qB2 - 1);
        displayB2(qB2);
        pB2 = qB2*50000;
        displaypriceB2(pB2);
    }
}

public void incrementB2 (View view) {
        qB2 = (qB2 + 1);
        displayB2(qB2);
        pB2 = qB2*50000;
        displaypriceB2(pB2);

}

private void displayB2(Integer number) {
    TextView quantityB2TextView = (TextView) findViewById(
            R.id.quantityB2);
    quantityB2TextView.setText("" + number);
}

private void displaypriceB2(Integer number) {
    TextView priceB2TextView = (TextView) findViewById(
            R.id.totalpriceB2);
    priceB2TextView.setText("Rp "+NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMANY).format(number));
}



}
```

Is it the problem come from the splashscreen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an error of the Android OS running marshmallow and nothing to do with your code, see this issue https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=192357

Try creating a new emulator using API 24 or 25